# Count number of different lines

Tags: awk, count, line

I have a file that has a lot of its lines repeated, it looks like this:

```
a
a
.
.
.
a
b
b
c
.
.
c
d
.
.
d
e
.
.
.
e
```

I need to count each line value only once so for example if the only possible values lines can be are from `a,b,c,d,e` the number i'm interested in is `5`.

here's how I've been counting all of the lines in the file:

```
wc -l file
```

which only gives me `n` times `a`, `m` times `b`, etc. and doesn't provide me any valuable information.

I sense this can be done using awk, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be awk? one way using shell-commands is

```
$ sort input.txt | uniq -c
     10 .
      3 a
      2 b
      2 c
      2 d
      2 e
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' input.txt
a 3
b 2
. 10
c 2
d 2
e 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do any programming for this, e.g.

```
$ sort -u input.txt | wc -l
```

`sort -u` sorts the input file removing any duplicates and the output is then piped to `wc -l` to generate a count of these unique lines.

Comment: I'm struggle to understand question, do OP want count of unique lines or count of how many times a line appears in text?

Comment: Well the OP says: *"I need to count each line value only once so for example if the only possible values lines can be are from a,b,c,d,e the number i'm interested in is 5."*. So it sounds like he just wants the total number of unique lines, but I agree that the question is not entirely clear.

Comment: I suggest you leave your answer as it could well be useful to someone in the future who arrives here looking to do something similar but slightly different. Have an up-vote from me anyway. ;-)

Comment: Thank you Paul it worked to perfection, but i have a question about this method, before it worked i accidentally used a blank file as the input file and it returned the number one, should i be worried about this, should i substract one from the result? Also i am new to this page how do i mark the question as answered

Comment: Well a blank file contains one empty line, I guess. As to whether you need to subtract one, you probably need to test this for yourself, and it *may* depend on whether the last line in the file has a terminating new line or not. I'm not in front of a *nix box right now so I can't easily test this but my guess is that it should behave as expected, so long as you don't have any trailing blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Given this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/lines.txt
a
a
.
.
.
a
b
b
c
.
.
c
d
.
.
d
e
.
.
.
```

You can also Perl to filter the type of lines to count. In this case, only letters:

```
$ perl -lane '$c{$1}++ if /^(\w+)/; END {print "$_: $c{$_}" foreach (sort keys%c); $s = keys %c; print "total uniques: $s"}' /tmp/lines.txt
a: 3
b: 2
c: 2
d: 2
e: 2
total uniques: 5
```

The total unique values is found by the number of key, value pairs in the hash `%c`

Similarly in awk, you can do:

```
$ awk '/\w+/{ a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]; c++} print "unique lines:", c}' /tmp/lines.txt
a 3
b 2
c 2
d 2
e 2
unique lines: 5
```

Or, cobble together a grep/uniq/wc solution:

```
$ grep -E '\w+' /tmp/lines.txt | uniq | wc -l
       5
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this in awk:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

That prints a line only the first time it is seen

Comment: This doesn't count anything

Comment: so it pipes into `wc -l`, I didn't think I needed to spell that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' file
```